# How can I configure dual headphones under Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio, headphones

Some laptops - in particular my Dell Studio XPS - have two headphone ports.

[image: Photo of XPS showing dual headphone ports]

Under Windows 7 currently the last pair of headphones plugged in begins to accept the output.

Is there something special that needs *to be configured* to allow both headphones to operate simultaneously?

[image: Windows 7 Control Panel]

What I have tried:

- Setting both as "default" - not an option (can't multi-select).
- Toggling the "default" - it just switches the active headphone.
- Toggling disable and enable - didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a similar laptop (studio 17), and it has two headphone jacks also.  Currently running Vista, I can stream audio to both headphone jacks/devices.  Try updated drivers from Dell, especially the IDT Audio Control Panel Driver...I have no problems, and it didn't require any set up...Is your machine an upgrade from Vista?

Comment: Yes it's an upgrade from Vista, but I don't have a lot of native Dell drivers left on it, will try the official dell drivers and comment on the outcome.

Comment: would appreciate that.

Comment: Thanks this worked great, the drivers I downloaded "Audio 92HD73C1 Drivers" worked great.

Answer (score 4):

Try updating your audio drivers; on some laptops it appears to be represented as a single device.

[image: Independent Dual Headphones]

What kind of audio hardware is in the laptop? Any device ID or driver version may help locate a fix for your problem. However I would see if newer drivers for Windows 7 for your audio device exist that may correct the problem right away.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there something special ... to
>   allow both headphones to operate
>   simultaneously?

A **[Speaker and Headphone Splitter](http://www.belkin.com/IWCatProductPage.process?Product_Id=149749#)** lets you connect two stereo headphones or speakers to the same mini-stereo jack.

[image]

[image]

Of course, if you're skilled with a soldering iron, you may disconnect the 2nd jack and split the connection of the 1st jack internally. :)

Comment: Doesn't this defeat the purpose of having two headphone jacks built-in to the laptop to begin with?

Comment: +1 to Jakobud, this isn't a fix.

Comment: Of course this is a 'fix' ... those two headphone jacks were never meant to be used simultaneously by the same source to begin with. you can drive a set of speakers with your media player, and still use a headset with Skype for example, but you cannot use both at the same time for the same application. hence the splitter is the perfect fix for the problem at hand.

Comment: Your solution, Molly, does allow two headphones to be connected but the underlying issue is to have the two jacks in the picture both work independantly.

Comment: @Craig - they do work independently, and that is exactly the problem, you can drive them with different applications (by design!), but you cannot have the same signal on both, and that's where you need a splitter.

Comment: Thanks for this answer Molly, this is my current work around, I have a splitter similar to the second image posted.

Comment: @Nick Josevski - are you able to get a signal on the 2nd jack from another application while using the 1st jack?

Comment: @Molly, no. It seems windows 7 with it's current built it audio drivers selects one to be the active device, so it's application independent.

Comment: @Nick Josevski - then get the Dell drivers, if no 7 drivers, the Vista drivers will work.

Comment: Yup, look at me not reading.  I will go hang my head in shame. :(  In that case, you are right on. :)

Answer (score 1):

[Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.html) (30$) have an audio repeater that let you do that (32 bit only)

Answer (score 0):

This is a restriction in Windows 7 (and also Vista, as I remember). You cannot output to more than one physical device at the same time. Internally, your headphone sockets are wired as two discrete devices, so Windows will not allow them both the operate at the same time.

The Virtual Audio Cable solution mentioned by fluxtendu is the only solution I have found that works. It does, however, cost money, and is a pain to get working on a 64bit system.

I'd stick with a cheapy headphone splitter instead :)