# Playing sound simultaneously over two output devices

Tags: windows-7, audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I configure dual headphones under Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/106618/how-can-i-configure-dual-headphones-under-windows-7)

Here is my scenario. I have a Windows 7 machine. This machine has two wireless headsets (I have two wireless dongles and two headphones). I am playing a movie and what I want to do is have the sound come out of both headsets. Right now I can have the sound come out of one or the other, but not out of both simultaneously. Is there a way to do this in Windows 7?

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. I don't have any laptop or output jacks like this question involves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the 1/8" stereo jack in a sound card or the built-in motherboard audio output, stereo y-cables are available. Plug the y-cable male jack into the audio output and each headset into the y-cable female sockets. It should work with any sound card.

**Edit:** Original question didn't identify the dongles. Since mine are analog, the answer given matches my experience. Dongles since identified to be USB sound card devices. Windows 7 doesn't support splitting the audio stream between two sound cards for simultaneous output from both via OS settings. Usually when you want this kind of behavior, you use **Virtual Audio Cable**.

Comment: They are wireless headsets

Comment: Then use a wireless Y cable ;)

Comment: Dongles mentioned, do they plug in? Then wireless is only between the dongle and the headset.

Comment: The dongles are just little devices that look similar to a USB drive. They plug into a USB port. The actual headset is [here](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/gaming/headsets/devices/wireless-gaming-headset-g930)

Comment: Better formulation of original question was needed. So how do they appear to the operating system. As a virtual sound card or speakers. Wherever this question is duplicated at, you need to reformulate your question so you will get a clearer answer. As this one is closed, over and out.

Comment: They appear as a sound card, not speakers

Comment: In that case, you need to look into a program called **Virtual Audio Cable**. The sound stream has to be split in software and sent to two separate destinations, something that Windows 7 isn't set up to do.

Comment: You're welcome. Nice features on those BTW. I'm going to look into them.

Answer (score 1):

I do it a little different.  I have a couple desktops, one set of monitor speakers, and a couple headphones now and then.  Little different scenario, but I think my solution would work, though it's not a Windows 7 solution per se.

I use a small mixing board.

In your case, take your sound output, run to the mixing board.  The mixing board should have a number of options for sound output.  You could run the stereo mix to your main computer speakers (if you roll that way), and plug any number of other devices (your headphones) into the headphone out, control room out, stereo sends, etc...

For what it's worth, [this](http://www.behringer.com/EN/Products/UB1202.aspx) is the one I use.  May be more mixer than you need, but there's room to grow, and they're not too terribly expensive.  A smaller sibling [here](http://www.behringer.com/EN/Products/UB502.aspx) is tiny, but actually still has 3 stereo outputs.  In any case, there are a number of options from various vendors that can accomplish the basic mixing you're trying to do.

Be careful though, you can get really used to the control :)

Comment: My sound is wireless though. There are no ports or jacks. What I have is [this product](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/gaming/headsets/devices/wireless-gaming-headset-g930)